# Shopify 3rd Party SSO WP Shopify Pro plugin

Tags: laravel, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api-node, shopify-app-bridge

Hello I have a client with a wordpress website using WP Shopify Pro plugin. I only have access to the shopify store is this plugin able to interact with a custom shopify app? The client sells online courses and would like a single sign on solution I have jwt experience but trying to picture how this is gonna integrate being new to shopify. I've only played with adding admin functionality.

We have a Shopify+Thinkific site bridge (we have Thinkific Premium, with SSO available), we want our Shopify customers log into their Thinific account. SSO
How can this be accomplished with jwt token? Anyone done anything similar?
https://developers.thinkific.com/more/sso/
https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/17056443-how-to-generate-a-shopify-api-token

Anyone have any examples of a custom app where they created successful 3rd party SSO interrogation  without multipass?